# Limits of functions having restricted domain

Tags: calculus

Suppose if we restrict the domain of the function $f(x)=x-5$ for all $x>5$ then $$\lim_{x \to 6}f(x)=1$$.This implies for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that whenever
$|x-6|<\delta$, $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$.But if we choose $\epsilon = 4$ then we get $-3 < x < 5$ how is this possible?

Comment: You will get $-3<f(x)<5$

Answer (score 0):

From definition of $\lim$, $\lim\limits_{x \to 6} f(x) = 1$ means for every $\varepsilon$ exists a $\delta$ such what whenever $|x - 6| < \delta$, $x \neq 5$ (we don't look at value at point when check limit) **and $x$ is from domain of $f$**, $|f(x) - 6| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $|f(x)-1|<4 \iff |x-5-1|<4 \iff |x-6|<4 \iff -4 <x-6 <4 \iff 2<x<10.$